# How to write response data of 2 different independent threadgroup into 2 different sheet of excel in JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, cell

There are 2 independent scenarios. I want to write the specific response data from each threadgroup but into 2 different excel sheet. Currently I am ble to write response data from first threadgroup to excel sheet1, how can I do the same for resonse data of second request to excel sheet2?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "Sheet" in [CSV files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) as they are plain text files.

If you want to distinguish [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) coming from different Thread Groups you can add __threadGroupName() function as the prefix/postfix for the Samplers - this way you will get the name of the Thread Group added to the sampler label

[image]

`__threadGroupName()` function is available since [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5)

Comment: I am asking for Excel, not csv. can we have in excel?

Comment: It is possible however you will need to write custom login in i.e. [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) library functions from the [Groovy Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black). However in this case you will need to take care of possible [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) yourself or use [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) for thread safety